# Pgfplots: let legend show two linestyles

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I do have a double axis plot which which compares two different things (part 1 on the left axis in solid, part two on the right axis in dashed) for different paramters which are common for both plots. Now, since in general the legend is crowed (more than 6 entries) I would like to join some legend entries. Meaning 2 lines (one from left and one from right) which have the same parameter should also be joined in the legend. Meaning, It would be nice to have two linestyles (solid and dashed) combined in one legend entry.

Here is my MWE for double axis plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=0,ymax=25,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  ]
  \addplot[solid] {x^2};
  \addlegendentry{plot A};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=0,ymax=25,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line*=bottom
  ]
  \addplot[dashed] {1.1*x^2};
  \addlegendentry{plot A};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The perfect outcome would be a legend entry like this:

```
_______
------- plot A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other approach is to use

```
 legend entries={plot A},
 legend image code/.code={%
 \draw[dashed] (0cm,-0.1cm) -- (0.5cm,-0.1cm);
 \draw[solid]  (0cm, 0.1cm) -- (0.5cm, 0.1cm);
    },
legend style={xshift=-0.5cm}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=0,ymax=25,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  ]
  \addplot[solid] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=0,ymax=25,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line*=bottom,
 legend entries={plot A},
 legend image code/.code={%
 \draw[dashed] (0cm,-0.1cm) -- (0.5cm,-0.1cm);
\draw[solid] (0cm, 0.1cm) -- (0.5cm, 0.1cm);
    },
legend style={xshift=-0.5cm}
  ]
  \addplot[dashed] {1.1*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us try to understand the problem.

You have 2 `axis` environments and each of them has a legend: no options are given for placement, hence we can really suppose that one legend covers the other one. Indeed, commenting the `\addlegendentry` in the second `axis` environment:

```
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=0,ymax=25,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line*=bottom
  ]
  \addplot[dashed] {1.1*x^2};
  %\addlegendentry{plot A};
\end{axis}
```

gives:

[image]

with solid line which in turn is simply the legend being covered previously.

The solution, is usually to set up the legend with a combination of `\addlegendentry` and `\addlegendimage`: this should be done only in one `axis` environment. I prefer the first one usually. By selecting the first `axis` environment, it is often necessary to add set `xtick` and/or `ytick` and/or `ztick` to `\empty` otherwise you end up repeating ticks. In your case you just have to set `xtick=\empty` as in y axis they differ.

In conclusion:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=0,ymax=25,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  legend style={
   xshift=-0.5cm, % <= avoid overlapping with the plots
  }
  ]
  \addlegendimage{draw}
  \addlegendentry{} % <= or use a \mbox{}
  \addlegendimage{dashed}
  \addlegendentry{plot A};
  \addplot[solid] {x^2};

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=0,ymax=25,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line*=none, % <= no need
  xtick=\empty,
  ]
  \addplot[dashed] {1.1*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Is it also possible to center the with respect to the lines in the legend?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you need some tricks that I would say Jesse's methods is better. However, I think center the text is not good and actually I would add a label for the solid plot to not confuse the reader.