# Using legend entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I made a code to display curves, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
       -1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -3.50000000e+00,         9.75000000e+00, -2.62500000e+01,  7.35937500e+01, -3.50000000e+00,         9.75000000e+00, -2.62500000e+01,  1.23005515e+02
       -5.78947368e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -3.07894737e+00,         6.97991690e+00, -1.45631652e+01,  3.17518749e+01, -3.07894737e+00,         6.97991690e+00, -1.45631652e+01,  5.91648918e+01
       -1.57894737e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -2.65789474e+00,         4.56440443e+00, -6.15144336e+00,  7.79163062e+00, -2.65789474e+00,         4.56440443e+00, -6.15144336e+00,  1.93708181e+01
        2.63157895e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -2.23684211e+00,         2.50346260e+00, -5.66955824e-01, -3.42580172e+00, -2.23684211e+00,         2.50346260e+00, -5.66955824e-01, -2.35859076e+00
        6.84210526e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -1.81578947e+00,         7.97091413e-01,  2.63817612e+00, -6.28491883e+00, -1.81578947e+00,         7.97091413e-01,  2.63817612e+00, -1.12508974e+01
        1.10526316e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -1.39473684e+00,        -5.54709141e-01,  3.91183117e+00, -4.41589541e+00, -1.39473684e+00,        -5.54709141e-01,  3.91183117e+00, -1.17793423e+01
        1.52631579e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -9.73684211e-01,        -1.55193906e+00,  3.70188803e+00, -6.94584190e-01, -9.73684211e-01,        -1.55193906e+00,  3.70188803e+00, -7.66284401e+00
        1.94736842e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -5.52631579e-01,        -2.19459834e+00,  2.45622540e+00,  2.75748416e+00, -5.52631579e-01,        -2.19459834e+00,  2.45622540e+00, -1.86599894e+00
        2.36842105e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -1.31578947e-01,        -2.48268698e+00,  6.22721971e-01,  4.57310099e+00, -1.31578947e-01,        -2.48268698e+00,  6.22721971e-01,  3.40091845e+00
        2.78947368e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.89473684e-01,        -2.41620499e+00, -1.35074355e+00,  4.13937964e+00,  2.89473684e-01,        -2.41620499e+00, -1.35074355e+00,  6.68195573e+00
        3.21052632e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  7.10526316e-01,        -1.99515235e+00, -3.01629246e+00,  1.59775549e+00,  7.10526316e-01,        -1.99515235e+00, -3.01629246e+00,  7.27548248e+00
        3.63157895e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.13157895e+00,        -1.21952909e+00, -3.92604607e+00, -2.15601404e+00,  1.13157895e+00,        -1.21952909e+00, -3.92604607e+00,  5.23419032e+00
        4.05263158e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.55263158e+00,        -8.93351801e-02, -3.63212567e+00, -5.47184956e+00,  1.55263158e+00,        -8.93351801e-02, -3.63212567e+00,  1.36509289e+00
        4.47368421e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.97368421e+00,         1.39542936e+00, -1.68665257e+00, -5.94534961e+00,  1.97368421e+00,         1.39542936e+00, -1.68665257e+00, -2.77047418e+00
        4.89473684e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.39473684e+00,         3.23476454e+00,  2.35825193e+00, -4.17790734e-01,  2.39473684e+00,         3.23476454e+00,  2.35825193e+00, -4.85685319e+00
        5.31578947e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.81578947e+00,         5.42867036e+00,  8.95046654e+00,  1.50238725e+01,  2.81578947e+00,         5.42867036e+00,  8.95046654e+00, -1.82406447e+00
        5.73684211e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.23684211e+00,         7.97714681e+00,  1.85378700e+01,  4.50470077e+01,  3.23684211e+00,         7.97714681e+00,  1.85378700e+01,  1.01521937e+01
        6.15789474e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.65789474e+00,         1.08801939e+01,  3.15683409e+01,  9.50733043e+01,  3.65789474e+00,         1.08801939e+01,  3.15683409e+01,  3.56505451e+01
        6.57894737e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  4.07894737e+00,         1.41378116e+01,  4.84897580e+01,  1.71278774e+02,  4.07894737e+00,         1.41378116e+01,  4.84897580e+01,  8.00039353e+01
        7.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  4.50000000e+00,         1.77500000e+01,  6.97500000e+01,  2.80593750e+02,  4.50000000e+00,         1.77500000e+01,  6.97500000e+01,  1.49299632e+02 
                
}\loadedtable
\begin{figure}[h]
\tikzset{ellipsenode/.style={draw, ellipse, thick, text width=5ex, align=center, inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-0.6,  xmax=6.6,
ymin=-17,  ymax=28,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=5,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=15, smooth,
legend entries={
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{0}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{1}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{2}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{3}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{4}(x)$
},                ]
\addplot[color=red] table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=blue]table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=green] table[x index=0,y index=3] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=purple] table[x index=0,y index=4] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=yellow] table[x index=0,y index=5] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-0.6,  xmax=6.6,
ymin=-17,  ymax=28,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=5,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=15, smooth,
legend entries={
        $Q^{(3)}_{0}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{1}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{2}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{3}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{4}(x)$
},    
   ]
\addplot[color=red] table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=blue]table[x index=0,y index=6] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=green] table[x index=0,y index=7] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=purple] table[x index=0,y index=8] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=yellow] table[x index=0,y index=9] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph of $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_n$ and $Q^{(3)}_n$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

But in the compilation result, I want the two description tables to be small enough to see the graphs better. An idea please

Comment: Just for fun, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230464/pgfplots-placing-legends-individually-to-the-end-of-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrt. [my comment with links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705129/using-legend-entries/705135#comment1752914_705135) here's a way to design or typeset your own legend. To better see the differences and to avoid clutter I put it as a separate answer.

[image: result-smaller]

#### Remarks

##### Preamble

For design it's better to use class `standalone`, as it adjusts to the "paper" size as needed. Package `xcolor` isn't needed here. We will need the tikzlibrary `matrix` to typeset the legend.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%\usepackage{xcolor}    % <<< not needed in pgfplots
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} % <<< to typeset the legend, later
```

##### Plotset

It's obsolete, as we don't use the built-in legend.

```
%    \pgfplotsset{
%       every axis legend/.append style={
%           at={(1.02,1)},
%           anchor=north west,
%       },
%    }
```

##### Axis environment

- let's put a title
- remove all legend statements
- add a `\label` AFTER each `\addplot ... ;`
- define a `\coordinate` to use it later, here called `(label)`

```
    \begin{axis}[
        ...
        no marks, samples=15, smooth,
        title=$Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_n(x)$; % <<<
    ]
    % <<< new: put labels, to reference them later ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot[color=red] table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};\label{plot:L1}
    ...
    
    % <<< new: legend will go here, in plot coordinates
    \coordinate (legend) at (.3,25);
    \end{axis}
```

##### Typeset your legend

The basic structure is `\matrix[...] at (legend) { ... };`, much like you'd do with a `\node`. You need to define some styles to see it the way you want it.

Think of `\matrix` as the Tikz-pendent to a `Latex table`. That's why you'll see the `& & \\` structure for one row of data. Inside you just typeset as with regular text, referencing all those plot labels set earlier. As with all references, they need a second compile after introducing changes.

```
    % ~~~ building your legend using a matrix (it's like a table within Tikz) ~~~~
    \matrix[
        draw,               % to see it, with
        matrix of nodes,    % see manual
        anchor=north west,  % upper left corner
        font={\tiny},       % use smaller font, if you like
    ] at (legend) {
        Index $n$: &&\\
        \ref{plot:L1} 0&\ref{plot:L2} 1&\ref{plot:L3} 2\\
        \ref{plot:L4} 3&\ref{plot:L5} 4&\\
    };
```

##### Result and code

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%\usepackage{xcolor}    % <<< not needed in pgfplots
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} % <<< to typeset the legend, later

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
           -1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -3.50000000e+00,         9.75000000e+00, -2.62500000e+01,  7.35937500e+01, -3.50000000e+00,         9.75000000e+00, -2.62500000e+01,  1.23005515e+02
           -5.78947368e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -3.07894737e+00,         6.97991690e+00, -1.45631652e+01,  3.17518749e+01, -3.07894737e+00,         6.97991690e+00, -1.45631652e+01,  5.91648918e+01
           -1.57894737e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -2.65789474e+00,         4.56440443e+00, -6.15144336e+00,  7.79163062e+00, -2.65789474e+00,         4.56440443e+00, -6.15144336e+00,  1.93708181e+01
            2.63157895e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -2.23684211e+00,         2.50346260e+00, -5.66955824e-01, -3.42580172e+00, -2.23684211e+00,         2.50346260e+00, -5.66955824e-01, -2.35859076e+00
            6.84210526e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -1.81578947e+00,         7.97091413e-01,  2.63817612e+00, -6.28491883e+00, -1.81578947e+00,         7.97091413e-01,  2.63817612e+00, -1.12508974e+01
            1.10526316e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -1.39473684e+00,        -5.54709141e-01,  3.91183117e+00, -4.41589541e+00, -1.39473684e+00,        -5.54709141e-01,  3.91183117e+00, -1.17793423e+01
            1.52631579e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -9.73684211e-01,        -1.55193906e+00,  3.70188803e+00, -6.94584190e-01, -9.73684211e-01,        -1.55193906e+00,  3.70188803e+00, -7.66284401e+00
            1.94736842e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -5.52631579e-01,        -2.19459834e+00,  2.45622540e+00,  2.75748416e+00, -5.52631579e-01,        -2.19459834e+00,  2.45622540e+00, -1.86599894e+00
            2.36842105e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -1.31578947e-01,        -2.48268698e+00,  6.22721971e-01,  4.57310099e+00, -1.31578947e-01,        -2.48268698e+00,  6.22721971e-01,  3.40091845e+00
            2.78947368e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.89473684e-01,        -2.41620499e+00, -1.35074355e+00,  4.13937964e+00,  2.89473684e-01,        -2.41620499e+00, -1.35074355e+00,  6.68195573e+00
            3.21052632e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  7.10526316e-01,        -1.99515235e+00, -3.01629246e+00,  1.59775549e+00,  7.10526316e-01,        -1.99515235e+00, -3.01629246e+00,  7.27548248e+00
            3.63157895e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.13157895e+00,        -1.21952909e+00, -3.92604607e+00, -2.15601404e+00,  1.13157895e+00,        -1.21952909e+00, -3.92604607e+00,  5.23419032e+00
            4.05263158e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.55263158e+00,        -8.93351801e-02, -3.63212567e+00, -5.47184956e+00,  1.55263158e+00,        -8.93351801e-02, -3.63212567e+00,  1.36509289e+00
            4.47368421e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.97368421e+00,         1.39542936e+00, -1.68665257e+00, -5.94534961e+00,  1.97368421e+00,         1.39542936e+00, -1.68665257e+00, -2.77047418e+00
            4.89473684e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.39473684e+00,         3.23476454e+00,  2.35825193e+00, -4.17790734e-01,  2.39473684e+00,         3.23476454e+00,  2.35825193e+00, -4.85685319e+00
            5.31578947e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.81578947e+00,         5.42867036e+00,  8.95046654e+00,  1.50238725e+01,  2.81578947e+00,         5.42867036e+00,  8.95046654e+00, -1.82406447e+00
            5.73684211e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.23684211e+00,         7.97714681e+00,  1.85378700e+01,  4.50470077e+01,  3.23684211e+00,         7.97714681e+00,  1.85378700e+01,  1.01521937e+01
            6.15789474e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.65789474e+00,         1.08801939e+01,  3.15683409e+01,  9.50733043e+01,  3.65789474e+00,         1.08801939e+01,  3.15683409e+01,  3.56505451e+01
            6.57894737e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  4.07894737e+00,         1.41378116e+01,  4.84897580e+01,  1.71278774e+02,  4.07894737e+00,         1.41378116e+01,  4.84897580e+01,  8.00039353e+01
            7.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  4.50000000e+00,         1.77500000e+01,  6.97500000e+01,  2.80593750e+02,  4.50000000e+00,         1.77500000e+01,  6.97500000e+01,  1.49299632e+02 
                
}\loadedtable

\tikzset{
    ellipsenode/.style={
        draw, ellipse, thick, text width=5ex, 
        align=center, inner sep=2pt
    }
}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \pgfplotsset{
%       every axis legend/.append style={
%           at={(1.02,1)},
%           anchor=north west,
%       },
%    }
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        xmin=-0.6,  xmax=6.6,
        ymin=-17,  ymax=28,
        axis on top,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=5,
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
        no marks, samples=15, smooth,
        title=$Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_n(x)$; % <<<
    ]
    % <<< new: put labels, to reference them later ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot[color=red] table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};\label{plot:L1}
    \addplot[color=blue]table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};\label{plot:L2}
    \addplot[color=green] table[x index=0,y index=3] {\loadedtable};\label{plot:L3}
    \addplot[color=purple] table[x index=0,y index=4] {\loadedtable};\label{plot:L4}
    \addplot[color=yellow] table[x index=0,y index=5] {\loadedtable};\label{plot:L5}
    
    % <<< new: legend will go here, in plot coordinates
    \coordinate (legend) at (.3,25);
    \end{axis}
    
    % ~~~ building your legend using a matrix (it's like a table within Tikz) ~~~~
    \matrix[
        draw,               % to see it, with
        matrix of nodes,    % see manual
        anchor=north west,  % upper left corner
        font={\tiny},       % use smaller font, if you like
    ] at (legend) {
        Index $n$: &&\\
        \ref{plot:L1} 0&\ref{plot:L2} 1&\ref{plot:L3} 2\\
        \ref{plot:L4} 3&\ref{plot:L5} 4&\\
    };  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. The easist thing would be to place the legend outside the drawing, say to the right. [Ch. "4.9.5 Legend Appearance" (pdf)](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) or ["20.9 Legend Appearance" (html)](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-axisdescription#sec-20.5) describes it in the pgfplots-manual.

I tried putting the legend above, but it doesn't look nice. You could also Tikz-draw your own legend using the approach described on the first page of said chapter:

```
% from said chapter, sth. like this:
 \matrix [style=every axis legend] {
    draw plot specification 1 & \node{legend 1}\\
...
```

An other alternative might be to introduce abbreviations for your many function in your article, and use those with the plots. When they are shorter, the two drawings might fit as a 1-line drawing as you posted.

The difference to your code is this line of code, which I added to both of your plots:

- specify the axis legend style
- recall from the manual, that (0,0) is lower left, (1,1) upper right corner
- place the legend slightly shifted to the upper right
- anchor its upper left corner (`north west`) to said position

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{                                 % <<<
    every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(1.02,1)},
        anchor=north west
    },
}
\begin{axis}[
```

[image: result]

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705129/using-legend-entries

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
       -1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -3.50000000e+00,         9.75000000e+00, -2.62500000e+01,  7.35937500e+01, -3.50000000e+00,         9.75000000e+00, -2.62500000e+01,  1.23005515e+02
       -5.78947368e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -3.07894737e+00,         6.97991690e+00, -1.45631652e+01,  3.17518749e+01, -3.07894737e+00,         6.97991690e+00, -1.45631652e+01,  5.91648918e+01
       -1.57894737e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -2.65789474e+00,         4.56440443e+00, -6.15144336e+00,  7.79163062e+00, -2.65789474e+00,         4.56440443e+00, -6.15144336e+00,  1.93708181e+01
        2.63157895e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -2.23684211e+00,         2.50346260e+00, -5.66955824e-01, -3.42580172e+00, -2.23684211e+00,         2.50346260e+00, -5.66955824e-01, -2.35859076e+00
        6.84210526e-01,  1.00000000e+00, -1.81578947e+00,         7.97091413e-01,  2.63817612e+00, -6.28491883e+00, -1.81578947e+00,         7.97091413e-01,  2.63817612e+00, -1.12508974e+01
        1.10526316e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -1.39473684e+00,        -5.54709141e-01,  3.91183117e+00, -4.41589541e+00, -1.39473684e+00,        -5.54709141e-01,  3.91183117e+00, -1.17793423e+01
        1.52631579e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -9.73684211e-01,        -1.55193906e+00,  3.70188803e+00, -6.94584190e-01, -9.73684211e-01,        -1.55193906e+00,  3.70188803e+00, -7.66284401e+00
        1.94736842e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -5.52631579e-01,        -2.19459834e+00,  2.45622540e+00,  2.75748416e+00, -5.52631579e-01,        -2.19459834e+00,  2.45622540e+00, -1.86599894e+00
        2.36842105e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -1.31578947e-01,        -2.48268698e+00,  6.22721971e-01,  4.57310099e+00, -1.31578947e-01,        -2.48268698e+00,  6.22721971e-01,  3.40091845e+00
        2.78947368e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.89473684e-01,        -2.41620499e+00, -1.35074355e+00,  4.13937964e+00,  2.89473684e-01,        -2.41620499e+00, -1.35074355e+00,  6.68195573e+00
        3.21052632e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  7.10526316e-01,        -1.99515235e+00, -3.01629246e+00,  1.59775549e+00,  7.10526316e-01,        -1.99515235e+00, -3.01629246e+00,  7.27548248e+00
        3.63157895e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.13157895e+00,        -1.21952909e+00, -3.92604607e+00, -2.15601404e+00,  1.13157895e+00,        -1.21952909e+00, -3.92604607e+00,  5.23419032e+00
        4.05263158e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.55263158e+00,        -8.93351801e-02, -3.63212567e+00, -5.47184956e+00,  1.55263158e+00,        -8.93351801e-02, -3.63212567e+00,  1.36509289e+00
        4.47368421e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.97368421e+00,         1.39542936e+00, -1.68665257e+00, -5.94534961e+00,  1.97368421e+00,         1.39542936e+00, -1.68665257e+00, -2.77047418e+00
        4.89473684e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.39473684e+00,         3.23476454e+00,  2.35825193e+00, -4.17790734e-01,  2.39473684e+00,         3.23476454e+00,  2.35825193e+00, -4.85685319e+00
        5.31578947e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.81578947e+00,         5.42867036e+00,  8.95046654e+00,  1.50238725e+01,  2.81578947e+00,         5.42867036e+00,  8.95046654e+00, -1.82406447e+00
        5.73684211e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.23684211e+00,         7.97714681e+00,  1.85378700e+01,  4.50470077e+01,  3.23684211e+00,         7.97714681e+00,  1.85378700e+01,  1.01521937e+01
        6.15789474e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.65789474e+00,         1.08801939e+01,  3.15683409e+01,  9.50733043e+01,  3.65789474e+00,         1.08801939e+01,  3.15683409e+01,  3.56505451e+01
        6.57894737e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  4.07894737e+00,         1.41378116e+01,  4.84897580e+01,  1.71278774e+02,  4.07894737e+00,         1.41378116e+01,  4.84897580e+01,  8.00039353e+01
        7.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  4.50000000e+00,         1.77500000e+01,  6.97500000e+01,  2.80593750e+02,  4.50000000e+00,         1.77500000e+01,  6.97500000e+01,  1.49299632e+02 
                
}\loadedtable
\begin{figure}[h]
\tikzset{ellipsenode/.style={draw, ellipse, thick, text width=5ex, align=center, inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(1.02,1)},
        anchor=north west
    },
}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-0.6,  xmax=6.6,
ymin=-17,  ymax=28,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=5,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=15, smooth,
legend entries={
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{0}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{1}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{2}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{3}(x)$,
        $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_{4}(x)$
},                ]
\addplot[color=red] table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=blue]table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=green] table[x index=0,y index=3] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=purple] table[x index=0,y index=4] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=yellow] table[x index=0,y index=5] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(1.02,1)},
        anchor=north west
    },
}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-0.6,  xmax=6.6,
ymin=-17,  ymax=28,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=5,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=15, smooth,
legend entries={
        $Q^{(3)}_{0}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{1}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{2}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{3}(x)$,
        $Q^{(3)}_{4}(x)$
},    
   ]
\addplot[color=red] table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=blue]table[x index=0,y index=6] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=green] table[x index=0,y index=7] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=purple] table[x index=0,y index=8] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[color=yellow] table[x index=0,y index=9] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph of $Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_n$ and $Q^{(3)}_n$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### P.S.:

For reference, this is what you get when moving the legends to the top of the plots:

[image: result2]

by using for both:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(.5,1.03)},
        anchor=south
    },
}
```

#### P.S. 2

Here's an alternative using a `title` and focusing only on the relevant change: `n`. However, even listing only 0, 1, ... doesn't make the legend small enough here.

[image: esult3]

```
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=-0.6,  xmax=6.6,
    ymin=-17,  ymax=28,
    axis on top,
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=5,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
    no marks, samples=15, smooth,
    legend entries={
            $n=0$,              % <<<
            $n=1$,
            $n=2$,
            $n=3$,
            $n=4$,
    },
    title=$Q^{1/2,1/2,5}_n(x)$; % <<<
]
```

Comment: BTW, here's an example which shows how to create a `\matrix`-based legend yourself; have a look at the end: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428135/245790 . // This anser is similar, but uses a different approach to the legends placement: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422997/245790 .