# tikz pgf - Use multiple images for one legendentry

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend

I have a plot in which I am showing experimentally obtained data and different models for the data. In order to keep the legend clean I want to summarise slightly different versions of the same model under one legend entry.

I came accross [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180650/pgfplots-let-legend-show-two-linestyles) similar question, but the proposed solution leads to all legend images being changed to the one given in `legend image code/.code`.
I also tried adding empty legend entries but that leads to the label being aligned with the first legend image.

Here is an MWE with the current legend:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
legend cell align={left},
legend style={at={(0.98,0.02)}, anchor=south east, draw=black},
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
    \addlegendimage{only marks, black, mark=square}
    \addlegendentry{Experiment};
    \addlegendimage{blue}
    \addlegendentry{Model 1-1};
        \addlegendimage{blue,dashed}
    \addlegendentry{Model 1-2};
        \addlegendimage{blue, dotted}
    \addlegendentry{Model 1-3};
    \addlegendimage{only marks, blue, mark=x}
    \addlegendentry{Model max};
        \addlegendimage{red}
        \addlegendentry{Model 2}
\addplot [black, mark=square, mark options={solid}, only marks]
table {%
0 0.1
0.25 0.4
0.5 0.6
0.75 0.7
1 0.9
};
\addplot [blue]
table {%
0 0
1 1.5
};
\addplot [blue, dashed]
table {%
0 0
1 0.9
};
\addplot [blue, dotted]
table {%
0 0
1 0.7
};
\addplot [blue, mark=x, mark options=solid, only marks]
table {%
1 0.95
};
\addplot [red]
table {%
0 0
0.1 0.3
0.2 0.5
0.3 0.6
0.4 0.65
0.5 0.7
1 1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from MWE]

And this is what I want my legend to look like:

[image: Desired legend]